# DeafultJmsListenerContainerFactory not consuming IBM MQ messages of larger sizes

Tags: java, ibm-mq, spring-jms

We are using `DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory` to consume messages from the IBM MQ, but it fails when we receive messages of larger size say 7.5 MB.
We have already increased the "Max Message length" for the queue.
Moreover, the message gets consumed when we shift to `SimpleJMSListenerContainerFactory`, but our requirement is to use `DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory` only.

Below is the exception we get while using `DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory`:

```
20/07/22 10:28:47.898.0N]  00000013 ] [com.ibm.mq.jmqi.remote.impl.RemoteSession[:/29f72f32][connectionId=414D51434E41504D3039312020202020636ED6629812D321,traceIdentifier=2,remoteTraceIdentifier=-1]]

[20/07/22 10:28:47.898.0O]  00000013     static  c.i.m.c.wmq.internal.WMQMessageConsumer                                ----+---  {  checkJmqiCallSuccess(String,HashMap<String , ? extends Object>,Pint,

Pint,JmqiEnvironment,String,WMQConsumerOwner,Hconn,boolean) [JMSWMQ2002] [{XMSC_DESTINATION_NAME=CIBISMBC.BONDLEND.JETTREPO.IN.Q3}] [1] [2080] [c.i.mq.jmqi.system.JmqiSystemEnvironment@343d1d25] [XN004

008] <as-before> [com.ibm.mq.jmqi.remote.impl.RemoteSession[:/29f72f32][connectionId=414D51434E41504D3039312020202020636ED6629812D321,traceIdentifier=2,remoteTraceIdentifier=-1]] [false]

[20/07/22 10:28:47.898.0P]  00000013  @7d25cab3  c.i.m.c.wmq.internal.WMQSession                                        ----+----  d  getJmqiMQ() getter [c.i.mq.ese.jmqi.ESEJMQI@4c0ab04f]

[20/07/22 10:28:47.898.0Q]  00000013     static  c.i.m.c.w.common.internal.Reason                                       ----+----  {  isImpossibleReason(int,int,JmqiSP) [2080(0x820)] [1(0x1)] [c.i.mq.e

se.jmqi.ESEJMQI@4c0ab04f]

[20/07/22 10:28:47.898.0R]  00000013     static  c.i.m.c.w.common.internal.Reason                                       ----+----+  }  isImpossibleReason(int,int)<exitIndex 4> returns [false] Boolean

[20/07/22 10:28:47.899.00]  00000013     static  c.i.m.c.w.common.internal.Reason                                       ----+----+  {  isConnectionBroken(int) [2080(0x820)]

[20/07/22 10:28:47.899.01]  00000013     static  c.i.m.c.w.common.internal.Reason                                       ----+----+  }  isConnectionBroken(int)<exitIndex 2> returns [false] Boolean

[20/07/22 10:28:47.899.02]  00000013     static  c.i.m.c.w.common.internal.Reason                                       ----+----+  {  createException(String,HashMap<String , ? extends Object>,int,int,

JmqiEnvironment) [JMSWMQ2002] [{XMSC_DESTINATION_NAME=CIBISMBC.BONDLEND.JETTREPO.IN.Q3}] [2080(0x820)] [1(0x1)] [c.i.mq.jmqi.system.JmqiSystemEnvironment@343d1d25]

[20/07/22 10:28:47.899.03]  00000013  @343d1d25  c.i.m.jmqi.system.JmqiSystemEnvironment                                ----+----+-  {  getComponentTls(int) [0(0x0)]

[20/07/22 10:28:47.899.04]  00000013  @343d1d25  c.i.m.jmqi.system.JmqiSystemEnvironment                                ----+----+-  }  getComponentTls(int) returns [c.i.mq.jmqi.system.JmqiTls@58512078

]

[20/07/22 10:28:47.899.05]  00000013  @343d1d25  c.i.m.jmqi.system.JmqiSystemEnvironment                                ----+----+-  d  getLastException() getter <null>

[20/07/22 10:28:47.899.06]  00000013     static  c.i.m.c.w.common.internal.Reason                                       ----+----+-  {  getCompCodeSymbol(int) [1(0x1)]

[20/07/22 10:28:47.899.07]  00000013     static  c.i.m.c.w.common.internal.Reason                                       ----+----+-  }  getCompCodeSymbol(int) returns [MQCC_WARNING] String

[20/07/22 10:28:47.899.08]  00000013     static  c.i.m.c.w.common.internal.Reason                                       ----+----+-  {  getReasonSymbol(int) [2080(0x820)]

[20/07/22 10:28:47.899.09]  00000013     static  c.i.m.c.w.common.internal.Reason                                       ----+----+-  }  getReasonSymbol(int) returns [MQRC_TRUNCATED_MSG_FAILED] String

[20/07/22 10:28:47.899.0A]  00000013  @3801c646  c.ibm.mq.MQException                                                   ----+----+-  {  <init>(String,String,int,int) [JMSCMQ0001: IBM MQ call failed wit

h compcode '1' ('MQCC_WARNING') reason '2080' ('MQRC_TRUNCATED_MSG_FAILED').] [JMSCMQ0001] [2080(0x820)] [1(0x1)]

[20/07/22 10:28:47.899.0B]  00000013  @3801c646  c.ibm.mq.MQException                                                   ----+----+-  }  <init>(String,String,int,int)

[20/07/22 10:28:47.899.0C]  00000013     static  c.i.m.c.w.common.internal.Reason                                       ----+----+-  {  reasonToException(int,String,String,String,String,HashMap<String

, ? extends Object>) [2080(0x820)] [JMSWMQ2002: Failed to get a message from destination 'CIBISMBC.BONDLEND.JETTREPO.IN.Q3'.] [JMSWMQ2002] [IBM MQ classes for JMS attempted to perform an MQGET; however

IBM MQ reported an error.] [Use the linked exception to determine the cause of this error.] [{XMSC_DESTINATION_NAME=CIBISMBC.BONDLEND.JETTREPO.IN.Q3}]

[20/07/22 10:28:47.899.0D]  00000013  @f400edc   c.i.m.client.jms.DetailedMessageEOFException                           ----+----+--  {  <init>(String,String,String,String,Map<String , ? extends Object

>) [JMSWMQ2002: Failed to get a message from destination 'CIBISMBC.BONDLEND.JETTREPO.IN.Q3'.] [JMSWMQ2002] [IBM MQ classes for JMS attempted to perform an MQGET; however IBM MQ reported an error.] [Use

the linked exception to determine the cause of this error.] [{XMSC_DESTINATION_NAME=CIBISMBC.BONDLEND.JETTREPO.IN.Q3}]

[20/07/22 10:28:47.899.0E]  00000013  @f400edc   c.i.m.client.jms.DetailedMessageEOFException                           ----+----+--  }  <init>(String,String,String,String,Map<String , ? extends Object

>)

[20/07/22 10:28:47.899.0F]  00000013     static  c.i.m.c.w.common.internal.Reason                                       ----+----+-  }  reasonToException(int,String,String,String,String,HashMap<String

, ? extends Object>) returns

[20/07/22 10:28:47.899.0F]  00000013 [com.ibm.msg.client.jms.DetailedMessageEOFException: JMSWMQ2002: Failed to get a message from destination 'CIBISMBC.BONDLEND.JETTREPO.IN.Q3'.

[20/07/22 10:28:47.899.0F]  00000013 IBM MQ classes for JMS attempted to perform an MQGET; however IBM MQ reported an error.

[20/07/22 10:28:47.899.0F]  00000013 Use the linked exception to determine the cause of this error.

[20/07/22 10:28:47.899.0F]  00000013 ]

[20/07/22 10:28:47.899.0G]  00000013  @f400edc   c.i.m.client.jms.DetailedMessageEOFException                           ----+----+-  d  setLinkedException(Exception) setter [com.ibm.mq.MQException: JMS

CMQ0001: IBM MQ call failed with compcode '1' ('MQCC_WARNING') reason '2080' ('MQRC_TRUNCATED_MSG_FAILED').]

[20/07/22 10:28:47.899.0H]  00000013     static  c.i.m.c.w.common.internal.Reason                                       ----+----+  }  createException(String,HashMap<String , ? extends Object>,int,int,

JmqiEnvironment)<exitIndex 2> returns <as-before>

[20/07/22 10:28:47.899.0I]  00000013     static  c.i.m.c.wmq.internal.WMQMessageConsumer                                ----+----  !  checkJmqiCallSuccess(String,HashMap<String , ? extends Object>,Pint

,Pint,JmqiEnvironment,String,WMQConsumerOwner,Hconn,boolean), JMSWMQ2002: Failed to get a message from destination 'CIBISMBC.BONDLEND.JETTREPO.IN.Q3'. [com.ibm.msg.client.jms.DetailedMessageEOFExceptio

n]





07:36:39.080 [org.springframework.jms.JmsListenerEndpointContainer#0-2] WARN  DefaultMessageListenerContainer -  - Setup of JMS message listener invoker failed for destination 'BONDLEND.Q3' - trying to recover. Cause: JMSWMQ2002: Failed to get a message from destination 'BONDLEND.Q3'.; nested exception is com.ibm.mq.MQException: JMSCMQ0001: IBM MQ call failed with compcode '1' ('MQCC_WARNING') reason '2080' ('MQRC_TRUNCATED_MSG_FAILED').

com.ibm.msg.client.jms.DetailedMessageEOFException: JMSWMQ2002: Failed to get a message from destination 'CIBISMBC.BONDLEND.JETTREPO.IN.Q3'.

        at com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.common.internal.Reason.reasonToException(Reason.java:539)

        at com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.common.internal.Reason.createException(Reason.java:215)

        at com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.internal.WMQMessageConsumer.checkJmqiCallSuccess(WMQMessageConsumer.java:222)

        at com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.internal.WMQMessageConsumer.checkJmqiCallSuccess(WMQMessageConsumer.java:156)

        at com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.internal.WMQConsumerShadow.getMsg(WMQConsumerShadow.java:1858)

        at com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.internal.WMQSyncConsumerShadow.receiveInternal(WMQSyncConsumerShadow.java:233)

        at com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.internal.WMQConsumerShadow.receive(WMQConsumerShadow.java:1461)

        at com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.internal.WMQMessageConsumer.receive(WMQMessageConsumer.java:674)

        at com.ibm.msg.client.jms.internal.JmsMessageConsumerImpl.receiveInboundMessage(JmsMessageConsumerImpl.java:1051)

        at com.ibm.msg.client.jms.internal.JmsMessageConsumerImpl.receive(JmsMessageConsumerImpl.java:667)

        at com.ibm.mq.jms.MQMessageConsumer.receive(MQMessageConsumer.java:209)

        at org.springframework.jms.connection.CachedMessageConsumer.receive(CachedMessageConsumer.java:86)

        at org.springframework.jms.support.destination.JmsDestinationAccessor.receiveFromConsumer(JmsDestinationAccessor.java:132)

        at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.receiveMessage(AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.java:431)

        at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.doReceiveAndExecute(AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.java:316)

        at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.receiveAndExecute(AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.java:270)

        at org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageListenerInvoker.invokeListener(DefaultMessageListenerContainer.java:1237)

        at org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageListenerInvoker.executeOngoingLoop(DefaultMessageListenerContainer.java:1227)

        at org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageListenerInvoker.run(DefaultMessageListenerContainer.java:1120)

        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

Caused by: com.ibm.mq.MQException: JMSCMQ0001: IBM MQ call failed with compcode '1' ('MQCC_WARNING') reason '2080' ('MQRC_TRUNCATED_MSG_FAILED').

        at com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.common.internal.Reason.createException(Reason.java:203)

        ... 18 common frames omitted
```

Comment: Did you increases the MAXMSGL of the SVRCONN?

Comment: @JoshMc yes, alreday done that

Comment: @JoshMc any idea about this ?

Comment: Do you have jms trace enabled?

Comment: @JoshMc Added the full trace in the post

Comment: I mean do you have a IBM MQ trace enabled?

Comment: @JoshMc Enabled and added in the post. You can see them now.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/246603/discussion-between-user1665581-and-joshmc).

Comment: Normally 2080 is only found in the trace,  JMS will automatically adjust the buffer and reGET the message